# Translate a new language

Tags: language

You are given the task as translator for a new language. There is no dictionary but you are given the following translations to help you.

- kisha dogafam kotirash     ‘Someone has shot the squire.’
- flori konekash dogredam     ‘The barmaid has seduced the colonel.’
- kisha drosin doflorim     ‘Someone strangles the barmaid.’
- doflorim lecha kowidash     ‘The milkman has found the barmaid.’
- pelin goli domelim   ‘The librarian calls the postmistress.’
- dobarnam kopelash rola     ‘The vicar has called the inspector.’
- barna dolecham kopetash     ‘The inspector has questioned the milkman.’
- widin dogafam fela.     ‘The doctor finds the squire.’

> You are given three tasks. First translate the following into English:
>
> - greda dofelam petin
> - kisha kodrosash dogolim
>
> Then translate this into the new language:
>
> - ‘The postmistress seduces the vicar.’

This question comes from http://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/field/field_document/OLAT%202009.pdf

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. The colonel questions the doctor.
>
>  2. Someone has strangled the librarian.
>
>  3. Meli nekin dorolam.

Explanations:

> By sentences 2 to 4 (and others) we can deduce that `do(X)m` is the accusative version of `(X)`. Therefore *greda* is *colonel* for instance.
>
>   When `(X)` is the root of a verb, `(X)in` is the simple present while `ko(X)ash` is the present perfect. You know that from `pelin` and `kopelash`.